# How does a method that returns an array/collection work with a single instance of an objects attributes?

Tags: arrays, class, oop, object, collections

I have a class called PaymentDetail. It has two attributes which are "Payment amount" and "order id". In this class I have a method called getPaymentDetails which connects to a relational database and returns a collection/array of more than one PaymentDetail (a collection/array of "Payment amount" and "order id" from a table).

Now in my study of object oriented programming and class diagrams (I am quite new to this), I have learnt that a class is an encapsulation of data (attributes) and methods that work with this data. My question is **how does a method, which returns an array, work on the data of an object especially when the data of the object represents a single instance of data for a single instance of an object.**

I intend on looping through the array and working with the data it contains and if possible have the object contribute to this however I don't know if it can.

Some of the possible solutions I have thought of is that multiple instances of the object could be mapped to the array however I thought that would be harsh on memory unless the object is recycled to handle the data in the array. I also thought that class names are traditionally not plural thus I didn't name the class PaymentDetails and have one of the attributes of type Array which would work with the array returned from the database.

Would someone please kindly clarify.

Comment: You confuse yourself. Obviously, a method that reads from somewhere (a database, a file or something) and constructs a collection of X objects does *not* work with a single X instance. However, the collection itself is a single instance of, well, the collection class you use.

Comment: I thought the collection itself is like a data type and not a class. I understand that the collection is a single instance of a collection but I thought classes are not collections could you please elaborate on what you meant by "collection class you use". Sorry I am quite new to oop. Are you referring to a predefined class that holds the collection of the retrieved objects?

Comment: But a class is just the OO way to deal with data types! In an OO language, like Java, you'll have a class like LinkedList<X>, that implements a collection (here: a list) of objects of type X. Also, you have an interface all classes that implement lists have to obey: List<X>. (The names may be different in different languages). Also, you can think of an array as a class that happens to have special syntactic support in the language you use.